# create patch file using .net windows application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

How to create patch file windows application using .net?how to override deployment patch file
???

Comment: What kind of patch file? Just plain text diff? Binary diff? MSI Patch (.msp)?

Answer (score 1):

This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367816%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN provides an example for creating a patch file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [Page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotnetpatching.aspx) help you.
It uses windows SDK and create standard patch files.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the link for more better understanding in [installation patches](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11373/How-to-create-installation-patches-for-VS-NET-depl) for VS.NET deployment projects